# HCIUART not working after Kernel Upgrade

Tags: pi-3b+, bluetooth, kernel, modules

For some experiments with BLE I did manually a kernel upgrade of a Raspberry Pi 3B+ by using (example; I tried a few versions of the official GitHub repository):

https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-6.4.y

I left the settings according to the guide (no other changes), meaning only the pi related configuration.

On the default 32-bit OS. I installed the kernel according to the official guide successfully

https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/linux_kernel.html

However, after this kernel upgrade HCIUART is not working anymore (actually my main issue lies in Bluetooth; after starting the Bluetooth control I got the warning "ho default host available" but I figured out that this lies in the HCIUART after some research). I already tried to restart the service, it gives (as its status) only the message that it is inactive (dead). This smells like a broken module; indeed, after checking the kernel module of HCIUART (trying to unload and load it) I got the error" exec format error".

I did not change anything on this module so I am wondering what is happening here. My only guess could be that there is still an old kernel module in use which is not compatible with my upgrade (but then would be the question, how is this possible?).

Does anyone have an idea? I couldn't find any solution after hours of research.